# How can I seperate my one long column name into columns

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have this CSV file
and this column name

```py
['school;sex;age;address;famsize;Pstatus;Medu;Fedu;Mjob;Fjob;reason;guardian;traveltime;studytime;failures;schoolsup;famsup;paid;activities;nursery;higher;internet;romantic;famrel;freetime;goout;Dalc;Walc;health;absences;G1;G2;G3']
```

This includes only 1 column but I want to separate them. I tried to use `regex`. separating them from `;` this syntax but I don't sure how I can do this

Comment: you may be able to just change the separator from `,` to `;` when loading!

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';')`

Comment: A little bit more info and you'll have a  reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example!

do you have a csv file with many columns and only one of them has additional records embedded with  `;` separators? `pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='[,;]')` will get them all in that case

Comment: Will you please edit your post and include a small sample of the CSV file? I'm confused why you're showing a single string in a Python list... what does that represent exactly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `example.csv` is mixing separators like

```
ID,Name,school;sex;age;address
1,Bart,Springfield;M;10;123 terrace st
1,Lisa,Springfield;M;8;123 terrace st
```

you can use the regexp `[,;]` to match either

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('example.csv', sep='[,;]')
```

[if the csv file extension is misleading -- not actually "comma separated values" but semicolon separated, you can just use `sep=';'`]

but watch out for something like a comments column that might have rows with values containing `;` meant as part of the text and not a separator: `bart's smart; doesn't apply himself`